# Aborts and beeps without error warning

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, crash, warning-messages

I have a piece of code that generates a figure, performing a calculation to generate each pixel. At a certain resolution it runs fine, but after a high enough resolution it fails. Mathematica beeps (sounds more line a 'dong') and just stops after a few seconds with no error warnings. How can I run some diagnostics on my code to try and figure out the problem?

I assume it's a memory problem, but when I use the MaxMemoryUsed[] command it was only ~20Mb which doesn't seem that much.

The code is shown below. I adjust the parameter 'res'. Up to res=12 it runs fine but thereafter it fails.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
startTime = AbsoluteTime[];
f[{rx_, ry_}] := 
 Module[{e1, e2, e3, d1, d2, d3, a, b, c, sol1, sol2, data, round, 
   rArray},
  {e1, e2, e3} = # & /@ {{0, -1}, {Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {-Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}};
  If[
   Norm[{rx, ry} - e1] <= 1/3 || Norm[{rx, ry} - e2] <= 1/3 || 
    Norm[{rx, ry} - e3] <= 1/3,
   Null,
   {d1, d2, d3} = # - {rx, ry} & /@ {e1, e2, e3};
   {a, b, c} = Norm[#]^-3 & /@ {d1, d2, d3};
   round = 0.000001;
   sol1 =
    If[0 <= ((b + c)^2 - a^2)/(4 b c) <= 1, 0,
     Re[{x, y} /. Solve[
        Round[a b (d2 - d1), round] Sin[{x, y}.(d1 - d2)]
          + Round[b c (d3 - d2), round] Sin[{x, y}.(d2 - d3)]
          + Round[a c (d3 - d1), round] Sin[{x, y}.(d1 - d3)]
         == 0, {x, y}]]];
   sol2 = 
    Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2 a b Cos[#.(d1 - d2)] + 
        2 b c Cos[#.(d2 - d3)] + 2 a c Cos[#.(d1 - d3)]] & /@ sol1;
   Min[sol2]
   ]
  ]
res = 20;
rArray = Table[{rx, ry}, {rx, -Sqrt[3]/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 
    Sqrt[3]/res}, {ry, 3/4, -3/4, -3/(2 res)}];
diagram = Map[f, rArray, {2}];
ArrayPlot[diagram, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> White, Null -> Gray}]
endTime = AbsoluteTime[] - startTime
```

Comment: In Mma v10 this code runs without any problem. In Mma v9 the kernel crashes while executing `diagram = Map[f, rArray, {2}];`

Comment: Does menu command **Help** > **Why the Beep?** tell you anything?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : "The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation."

Comment: @Karsten7. : thanks for the info. Could be a good excuse to get my supervisor to upgrade! =P

Comment: What's the use of the `Null` in the `If` function?

Comment: It also runs on Mma v9 it the precision of rArray is reduced, e.g. `diagram = Map[f, SetPrecision[rArray, 20], {2}];`. However, the result looks different than in v10. My guess is that the problem is relatet to the use of `Round`.

Comment: @Karsten7.: hmmm ok, how different? It seemed I had to used Round otherwise it wouldn't run at all.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I'm using Null just as a marker to indicate points where particles physically can't be brought together and thus colour it grey.

Comment: BTW, the kernel quitting is why `MaxMemoryUsed[]` returns 20 MB -- the kernel has to be restarted to execute `MaxMemoryUsed[]`, and you're getting the memory usage of the new kernel.

Comment: If you put the definition of f in a separate cell it seems to work fine.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries unfortunately not for me :(

Comment: I added `N` to `rArray = Table[N@{rx, ry}, {rx, -Sqrt[3]/2, Sqrt[3]/2, Sqrt[3]/res}, {ry, 3/4, -3/4, -3/(2 res)}]` and it worked for me (V9.0.1).  Oddly, thereafter, the original code worked, too.  (It did not work before.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 when I tried your suggestion I get the warning "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result" and the resulting plot is only 2 colour whereas I'm expecting a gradient of colours. However it did work for higher resolutions than it has before!

Comment: @MichaelE2 maybe you could post the whole code you used an an answer briefly so I can copy and paste and see if it works. Maybe something's got lost in translation through all this. Thanks.

Comment: @TomJS See [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8UurZ.png).

Comment: It's very odd.  If I follow the two-cell procedure in @Sjoerd's picture, I get different results at different times.  Sometimes the it finishes and everything is fine; sometimes the kernel dies right after producing the plot; sometime the kernel dies while mapping `f` before getting to the plot.  I thought it depended on how I executed the cells: queue both simultaneously, execute first/wait until finished/execute second, execute first/queue second before first is finished.  But several trials have not produced completely consistent results.  I'm confused.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Perhaps you're in a borderline memory squeeze?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The memory usage of the kernel stays consistently under 70MB.  I have 16GB.  (Unless "memory squeeze" means something else.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Just trying to explain your intermittent results. Doesn't look like memory is an issue ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Get this code working

You can get the code running under Mma v9, by adding options to `Solve`:
Adding

```
VerifySolutions -> False
```

should work.
And also

```
VerifySolutions -> True, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision
```

works on my PC, if `res` isn't too big.
For bigger `res` (tested for 50)

```
VerifySolutions -> False, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision
```

will make the code working.

---

### Parallelization

You didn't ask for this, but if you execute

```
ParallelEvaluate[Off[Solve::ifun]]
```

before the posted code, the `Solve::ifun` messages will be switched off.
And replacing `Map` with `ParallelMap`:

```
diagram=ParallelMap[f,rArray,{2}];
```

will speed up the code significantly, if you have more than one core.

Comment: Brilliant! This is working for me and also you've cut my computation time in half, which is great because I'm doing a lot of this sort of thing and often I leave things computing for hours, so thanks!