# Possible bug in Dynamic

Tags: dynamic, crash

The code below crashes the Mathematica kernel in version 10 (not in V9) every time I run it on Windows and on Mac OS. I've sent it to WRI, but was told that they could not reproduce the crash.

Does this really only crash on my computers? Could somebody else test it with Mathematica 10?

```
pts = Flatten[
   Table[Through[{Cos, Sin}[α]] r, {α, 0., 
     360 ° - 10^-5, 60 °}, {r, 1, 2}], 1];

LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
 Dynamic@Show[
   Graphics[{Arrow /@ Partition[pts, 2]}], {a, b} = 
    Transpose[Map[Module[{p1, p2, d}, {p1, p2} = #;
        d = p2 - p1;
        {d, p1.d}] &, Partition[pts, 2]]];
   RegionPlot[And @@ Thread[a.{x, y} < b], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]]]

ContourPlot[
 Total[Log[Clip[b - a.{x, y}, {10^-10, ∞}]]], {x, -2, 
  2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-10, 0}]
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the `crash` tag; in addition to categorization it helps to warn people who blindly execute Question code. :-)

Comment: Crash confirmed in a fresh kernel.  Version 10.0.0 under Windows.

Comment: Crashes for me (Mac OSX), **if** I put the code in a single cell.  If I put the `ContourPlot` in a separate cell, it does not crash.  Reminds me of my experience with [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55654/aborts-and-beeps-without-error-warning), which seems to have nothing to do with `Dynamic`.

Comment: I can confirm the crash, regardless of whether I put the ContourPlot in a separate cell or not.  OS X 10.9.4, Mathematica 10.0.0.

Comment: FWIW, `Dynamic@Refresh[ContourPlot[...], None]` does not crash.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**: This is a rewrite.  The original answer was more or less an extended comment containing some seemingly relevant clues.  I've tracked down two probable issues, each related to a system variable, and there may be others.  At least in either case, the crashing can be triggered or prevented.*  It turns out that `Dynamic@RegionPlot[..]` depends on the variables `$PlotTheme` and `$DisplayFunction` and that evaluating `ContourPlot` triggers an update.  Beyond this, I'm not sure how the crash occurs.  The evaluation of `ContourPlot` triggers an update of `RegionPlot`.  This apparently occurs simultaneously, the `ContourPlot` being requested via the main link and the `RegionPlot` via the preemptive link.  It would not be surprising if one interferes with the other and leads to the crash.

The following shows `ContourPlot` tickles `$PlotTheme` and `$DisplayFunction`.  Evaluate `ContourPlot` repeatedly and see `pt` and `df` be incremented.

```
pt = 0; df = 0;
Dynamic[{++pt, $PlotTheme}, TrackedSymbols :> {$PlotTheme}]
Dynamic[{++df, $DisplayFunction}, TrackedSymbols :> {$DisplayFunction}]

(* new cell *)
ContourPlot[x + y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

The following shows that `Dynamic@RegionPlot` depends on `$PlotTheme` and `$DisplayFunction`.  Evaluate the plot and then evaluate the others in turn and see the `RegionPlot` be updated.

```
Dynamic[RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]]
```

[image]

```
$DisplayFunction = Hold
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
$DisplayFunction = Identity
$PlotTheme = "Web"
```

[image]

```
$PlotTheme = Automatic
```

---

Here is a simple workaround: add `TrackedSymbols :> {pts}`.  Below you can uncomment the other symbols, if you wish to observe the kernel crashing.  (It seems to be a race situation. It doesn't always crash when you evaluate the `ContourPlot`, but it usually does.  It crashes if you uncomment one, the other, or both symbols.)

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
 Dynamic[Show[
   Graphics[{Arrow /@ Partition[pts, 2]}], {a1, b1} = 
    Transpose[Map[Module[{p1, p2, d}, {p1, p2} = #;
        d = p2 - p1;
        {d, p1.d}] &, Partition[pts, 2]]];
   RegionPlot[
    And @@ Thread[a1.{x1, y1} < b1], {x1, -2, 2}, {y1, -2, 2}]], 
  TrackedSymbols :> {pts(*, $PlotTheme*)(*, $DisplayFunction*)}]]
```

---

*Acknowledgement*: [Karsten 7.'s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18476/karsten-7) observation about `SynchronousUpdating -> False` led me to observe that evaluating `ContourPlot` causes the dynamic `RegionPlot` to be reevaluated.  Further investigation led me as far as `$PlotTheme` and `$DisplayFunction`.

Comment: +1 Nice troubleshooting. Wrapping the `ContourPlot` in `PreemptProtect` seems to work too.

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks, I'd forgotten about `PreemptProtect`.  It makes sense it would work.

Comment: @SimonWoods I find that, if all code is in one cell, while `PreemptProtect@ContourPlot[..]` prevents a crash for the first execution of both plots, the next time I execute both plots, things lock up and the dynamic updating of `Graphics`/`RegionPlot` does not finish.  Also, `{a, b}` is not initialized when `ContourPlot` is executed.  If the code for the plots is in separate cells, then everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

The `x` and `y` of the `ContourPlot` are interfering with the `x` and `y` inside of `Dynamic`.
If you use for example

```
ContourPlot[Total[Log[Clip[b-a.{x2,y2},{10^-10,\[Infinity]}]]],{x2,-2,2},{y2,-2,2},PlotRange->{-10,0}]
```

it'll not crash.
I guess this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: It still crashes for me (Mac OSX).

Comment: This works for me. Windows 8.1

Comment: I'm using v10.0.0 under Win7

Comment: Yes, putting the `ContourPlot` inside `Module[{x,y}, ...` works, too. (I actually included that workaround in my WRI support ticket, but forgot it in the question here...)

Comment: @nikie `Module[{x,y},...]` does not work for me.  I don't get consistent results, as if there is a race in the front end for what is updated.  I sometimes get errors, such as "Unset::wrsym: Symbol DensityPlot is Protected" and `RegionPlot` still unevaluated.

Comment: @MichaelE2: You're right, this looks like a race condition: If I assign all Mathematica processes to a single CPU core, it doesn't crash anymore (or at least not that often). Maybe the WRI support people can't reproduce it because they have single core CPUs?

Answer (score 2):

The more general solution to this problem is to make use of the Option `SynchronousUpdating->False`:

```
pts=Flatten[Table[Through[{Cos,Sin}[\[Alpha]]] r,{\[Alpha],0.,360 \[Degree]-10^-5,60 \[Degree]},{r,1,2}],1];
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
  Dynamic[Show[
   Graphics[{Arrow /@ Partition[pts, 2]}], {a, b} = 
    Transpose[Map[Module[{p1, p2, d}, {p1, p2} = #;
      d = p2 - p1;
      {d, p1.d}] &, Partition[pts, 2]]];
   RegionPlot[And @@ Thread[a.{x, y} < b], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]], 
   SynchronousUpdating -> False]]
```

and than

```
ContourPlot[Total[Log[Clip[b-a.{x,y},{10^-10,\[Infinity]}]]],{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},PlotRange->{-10,0}]
```

Comment: @MichaelE2 does this also work on a Mac?

Comment: Sorry, somehow I wasn't pinged.  It does work (at least for the several times I tried it).  Of course, `a`, `b` are not set until the `RegionPlot` is updated.  Also executing `ContourPlot[Total[Log[Clip[b2 - a2.{x2, y2}, {10^-10, \[Infinity]}]]], {x2, -2, 2}, {y2, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-10, 0}]` causes the `RegionPlot` to update.  (The variables `a2`, `b2` are copies of `a`, `b`, resp.)

Answer (score 0):

This, I think, is a simplified version of the issue:
If one executes

```
Dynamic[Print[x]; x]
```

and than with the Messages window open

```
Plot[x,{x,-2,2}]
```

`x` is printet into the Messages window two times whenever the prior `Plot` comment is executed (using Mma v10).
However, in Mma v9 only one `x` is printed into the Messages window for every execution of the `Plot` command.

Comment: Please note that on my system if instead of `x`, `y`, I use `RegionPlot[And @@ Thread[a.{x1, y1} < b], {x1, -2, 2}, {y1, -2, 2}]` and `ContourPlot[Total[Log[Clip[b - a.{x2, y2}, {10^-10, \[Infinity]}]]], {x2, -2, 2}, {y2, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-10, 0}]` causes a crash.  So at least for this example on a Mac, there's something beyond a symbol clash.

Comment: @MichaelE2 what if you also lokalize a and b for the `ContourPlot`?

Comment: I tried that.  And localizing a, b, x and y.  They all crash.