# Crash when dynamically updating ListLinePlot

Tags: dynamic, crash

I was trying to solve a wave problem using numerical methods. The code below crashes each time I run it on Windows with version 10.2.

```
data = {ConstantArray[0, 121]};
matA[n_, alpha_, dx_] := 
  Block[{result},
    result = 
      SparseArray[
        {{i_, i_} -> alpha/dx, 
        {i_, j_} /; i - j == 1 -> (-1-alpha)/(2dx), 
        {i_, j_} /; j-i == 1 -> (1 - alpha)/(2dx)}, n + 1];
    result[[n + 1, -2 ;; -1]] = {-1/dx, 1/dx};
    result[[1, 1 ;; 2]] = {0, 0};
    result]
bc1[t_] := 1 + 0.1 Sin[4t];
dpdt[n_, mat_, source_, alpha_, dx_, x_, t_] := 
  Block[{rho = x},
    rho[[1, 1]] = source[t];
    -(matA[n, alpha, dx].(rho*{1 + 0.5 Cos[#]& /@ 
      Table[dx*j, {j, 0, n }]}\[Transpose])) // N];
RK4ODEs[n_, init_, mat_, source_, alpha_, dx_, dt_, time_] :=
  Fold[
    Block[{s, coeff1 = {0, 0.5, 0.5, 1}, coeff2 ={1/6, 1/3, 1/3, 1/6}},
      s[0] = 0;
      Do[
        s[i] = 
          dpdt[n, mat, source, alpha, dx, 
               #1 + coeff1[[i]]*s[i - 1]*dt, #2 + coeff1[[i]]*dt], 
        {i,1,4}]//N;
      data = #1 + (1/6 s[1] + 1/3 s[2] + 1/3 s[3] + 1/6 s[4])*dt//N;
      data[[1, 1]] = source[#2 + dt];
      data2 = data;
      data2]&,
    init,
    Table[dt*j, {j, 0, Floor[time/dt]}]]
Dynamic[
  Module[{}, 
    ListLinePlot[data2//Transpose, PlotRange->{All,All}]], 
    TrackedSymbols :> data2]
Dynamic[data2 // Transpose]
sol1 = 
  RK4ODEs[150, {ConstantArray[1, 151]}\[Transpose], matA, bc1, 0.0, 0.09, 0.025, 30];
```

I noticed that if I comment out the line that dynamically updates the ListLinePlot, then the kernel will not crash, which means the problem is probably due to dynamically updating `ListLinePlot`. I have also tried several methods in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55855/possible-bug-in-dynamic), i.e., adding `TrackedSymbols:>{data2}`, wrapping `ListLinePlot` with `Module`, but neither works. In fact, `TrackedSymbols:>{data2}` can sometimes force the evaluation to continue (but you can see that something is still wrong because many frames pink and the red error box is flashing around the plot), however, the kernel will crash eventually. Besides, the crash is rather random in terms of time of occurrence, i.e., sometimes it crashes as soon as I ran the code, and sometimes it crashes after 10 sec or so. The error message popped up was `"Transpose[data2] is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers. "` and `An unknown box name (ToBoxes) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression.`

I am also wondering if there is a better way of visualizing `data2`, which contains information of the points at each time step. Of course, I could use `FoldList` to collect the information of the points at all time steps and then use `ListAnimate` to generate the movie. However, the problem with this is that it consumes as much as 3GB RAM since it stores the information of all points at all time steps. Besides, I have to wait until `RK4ODEs` finishes evaluation before I could call `ListAnimate`, and `ListAnimate` also takes a lot of time to generate the movie.

P.S: I am required to implement RK4 myself, so I am not allowed to use `NDSolve`.

Comment: As an alternative: are you aware that you can configure `NDSolve[]` to use the classical Runge-Kutta coefficients?

Comment: @J.M. I am required to implement RK4 by myself......

Comment: Try this `Dynamic[
 If[ (* some test on data2 here *),
  ListLinePlot[data2 // Transpose, PlotRange -> {All, All}],
  (* else *)
  Spacer[0]
  ], TrackedSymbols :> {data2}]`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch It still crashes....

Comment: what test did you apply?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Since `data2` should be plotted each time it is updated by `RK4ODEs`, so I have to use a test that always returns `True`. In my case, I chose `Length@data2==151`.

Comment: I don't know if this will have any effect on your crashing, but 
`Dynamic[ListLinePlot[data2 // Transpose, PlotRange -> {All, All}],  TrackedSymbols :> {data2}]` is a better way to express your dynamic plot expression.

Comment: @m_goldberg I tried this, but unfortunately the crash still occurs.

Comment: At this point I would punt and try working with `Monitor`.  You can also dispense with dynamics all together, generate tables of figures and use `ListAnimate`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `^` before `Transpose` is a typo here. Can you verify that and fix it so everybody who comes across the question doesn't need to deal with it.

Comment: with the `FoldList` approach , all the data is only 2Mb.  `ListAnimate` takes a minute or two to compose, slow but not unreasonable. with `ListAnimate` you can also plot say every 10th frame so it loads and runs faster.

Comment: @george2079 Thank you and I have corrected the typo. I know that I could use `ListAnimate` anyway, but I am just curious what went wrong with `Dynamic`. Could you help me figure out this?

Answer (score 1):

I can not confirm the crash, neither in 10.2 nor in 10.3 on Linux. I did, however change the following line:

```
matA[n, alpha, dx].(rho *Transpose[{1 + 0.5 Cos[#] & /@ Table[dx*j, {j, 0, n}]}])
```

The other notation for `Transpose` did not seem to work. Also, some of the frames during the dynamic pink but that might be a different issue. It certainly did not crash for me. (Perhaps it does for a different OS - then it were good to report this to the support of Wolfram Research) - Looks nice when it runs...

Comment: You mentioned that some frames pink, do you mean that the plot is sometimes surrounded by a red box with a pink background, which suggests that there are some errors during evaluation?

Comment: @zjx1805, yes, exactly.

Comment: I think that `TrackedSymbols` can sometimes suppress the error so that the evaluation can continue, but on my computer the kernel still will crash after some time. My thought is that perhaps `data2` is updating so fast that `ListLinePlot` does not have enough time to draw them? BTW, what do you think is the reason for the pinked frame?

Comment: On 10.1 *all* of the frames are pink with the error  being `data2` is not a valid symbol for `TrackedSymbols`.  It appears to work fine if you just omit tracked symbols all together.  (see above comment by MikeH for correct TrackedSymbols syntax , `{}` required)

Comment: @george2079 Removing `TrackedSymbols` doesn't solve the problem, it still crashes each time I run it, and the difference is just how soon it will crash. BTW, I am just wondering why it crashes even without `TrackedSymbols`?

Comment: Tried it for fun, and I get a kernel crash in Mma11 after a short while.

Comment: @Pirx, yes, I see it on 11.0 on Linux. Will report it.